# How to add a xml fragment to an element

Tags: lxml

I am converting from Amara (http://xml3k.org/Amara/Tutorial) to lxml, in Amara I could do:

```
for wxp in self.Points:
        points.xml_append_fragment('<point><x>%i</x><y>%i</y></point>' % (wxp[0], wxp[1]))
```

Where 'points' is an element, how can I do this with lxml.objectify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

```
for wxp in self.Points:
            #points.xml_append_fragment('<point><x>%i</x><y>%i</y></point>' % (wxp[0], wxp[1]))
            point = xmlu.addElement(points, u'point', ns=None)
            xmlu.addElementPlusValue(point, u'x', wxp[0])
            xmlu.addElementPlusValue(point, u'y', wxp[1])
```

'addElement' is basically doing a `objectify.SubElement` and 'addElementPlusValue' is doing a `setattr(element, name, value)`